# Append Previous Word Python

Tags: python, string, list

The Program must accept a string S with multiple words as the input.For each word W, if it's first character is equal to the last character of the previous word then the previous word should be added in the end(append) to the word W. Else the word must be considered to be printed in the next Line.

```
  def prev(a):
    b=[]
    for i in range(len(a)):

        t=a[i][0]
        if i-1>=0:
            if a[i-1][-1].lower()==t.lower():
                a[i]+=a[i-1]
                b.append(a[i-1])
    return a,b
 a=input().strip().split(" ")
 a,b=prev(a)
 for i in a:
     if i not in b:
         print(i)
```

Is there any fast way of accomplishing this

[Some Examples Input and Outpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PznKX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not benchmark it, but I would give a try to a [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)). The functools module provides the [reduce function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
>>> s = "are all levels lavendar lemon maverick king of gamblers"
```

Split the string on spaces:

```
>>> t = s.split(" ")
>>> t
['are', 'all', 'levels', 'lavendar', 'lemon', 'maverick', 'king', 'of', 'gamblers']
```

And fold the list:

```
>>> import functools
>>> u = functools.reduce(lambda acc, x: acc[:-1] + [x+acc[-1]] if acc and x and acc[-1][-1] == x[0] else acc + [x], t, [])
>>> u
['are', 'lemonlavendarlevelsall', 'kingmaverick', 'of', 'gamblers']
```

We start with an empty list `[]`. There are two cases: if the last letter of the previous word (or packed word) is the first letter of the current word (`acc[-1][-1] == x[0]`), then we insert the current word before the previous word (or packed word): `acc[:-1] + [x+acc[-1]]`. Else we add the current word to the list.

Now just print the result:

```
>>> print("\\n".join(u))
are
lemonlavendarlevelsall
kingmaverick
of
gamblers
```

---

Another version, based on the observation that if we have a word `w[i]` with the last letter `c=w[i][-1]` so that `w[i+1][0] = c`, then we build `w[i+1]+w[i]` and the last letter will be `c` again: we just have to check if the next words `w[i+2], w[i+3], ...` start with `c` etc. If not, start a new line.

```
s = "are all levels lavendar lemon maverick king of gamblers"
t = s.split(" ")
i = 0
while i < len(t):
    c = t[i][-1]
    j = i+1
    cur = [t[i]]

    while j<len(t) and t[j][0] == c:
        cur.insert(0, t[j])
        j += 1
    print("".join(cur))
    i = j
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to efficiently implement the algorithm you are looking for. This is because the appends and pops from either side of the deque are efficient with the complexity of `O(1)` in either direction.

Use:

```
from collections import deque

def word_magic(string):
    tokens = deque(string.split())
    words = []
    while tokens:
        curr_word = tokens.popleft()
        if not tokens:
            words.append(curr_word)
            break

        next_word = tokens[0]
        if curr_word[-1] == next_word[0]:
            tokens.popleft()
            tokens.appendleft(next_word + curr_word)
            continue

        words.append(curr_word)

    return words
```

Calling the function:

```
# Example 1
words = word_magic("are all levels lavendar lemon maverick king of gamblers")
print("\n".join(words))

# Example 2
words = word_magic("crab boy yesterday yellow wing game engine eat top")
print("\n".join(words))
```

This prints:

```
are
lemonlavendarlevelsall
kingmaverick
of
gamblers

boycrab
yellowyesterday
gamewing
eatengine
top
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "are all levels lavendar lemon maverick king of gamblers".split()

words = list(reversed(s))  # Reverse the list because we're poping from the end
while words:
    first = words.pop()
    rest = []
    while words and words[-1][0] == first[-1]:
        rest.append(words.pop())
    print("".join([*rest, first]))
```

For every word, look ahead while you find words that start with the same letter as that word (the word you're on) ends with. Then print those words (that start with the letter) followed by that word (the word that ends with the letter) and skip to the word after the last word that you found.

You can write the same code using an index instead of [`list.pop`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

```
words = "are all levels lavendar lemon maverick king of gamblers".split()

i = 0
while i < len(words):
    first = words[i]
    i += 1

    rest = []
    while i < len(words) and words[i][0] == first[-1]:
        rest.append(words[i])
        i += 1

    print("".join([*rest, first]))
```